# What is the behavior of RegistryOptions.Volatile?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am setting up a C# Windows program and I want it to include a 30-day free trial period.

I wanted to keep expiration date info in the Windows registry.

I was using `RegistryKey.CreateSubKey` with the `RegistryOptions.Volatile` option. I read that this just updates memory, not the registry files.

I saw this as a good way to test my features - set up subkeys and values that will only be around until I reboot my machine. When I get the desired behavior from the code, switch it over to `RegistryOptions.None`, which would create permanent registry entries.

Any things I need to be aware of?

Comment: Why not test it using `RegistryOptions.None` and use `RegEdit.exe` to delete your key/s when you want to re-test? It would save rebooting every time you wanted to re-test. Alternatively set up proper Test Cases which create the required keys, then automatically delete after the test has run. Also assuming you don't want users to be able reset the trial period, you'll need more than just a Registry Entry alone.

Comment: I was doing that yesterday and started getting some "unexpected behavior" from an FTP program. It "seems" the problem was related to file permissions, but it was too coincidental from my point of view. I was hoping to get some insight into the differences between the Volatile and None options. Hopefully, I can hear about possible problems before I create them. And yes, I'll have the program talking with my server to try to catch those who would hack the trial period. Thanks!